# Select the most recent record for a user without using limit

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a safe way to get the most recent record for a id and user in this case without using limit like I'm doing below?

**Table**

```
"id"    "head"  "type"  "updated"   "userId"    "addedDate"
"1"     "2"     "0"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-24 11:33:04"
"1"     "2"     "1"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-24 11:56:35"
"2"     "2"     "0"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-24 11:55:40"
"2"     "2"     "1"     "0"         "1"         "2013-11-24 11:56:28"
```

**Current sql**

```
select id, addedDate from test 
where id = 1 and userId = 1 order by addedDate desc limit 1;
```

**Trying to achieve (for the above sql without using limit)**

```
"id"    "head"  "type"  "updated"   "userId"    "addedDate"
"1"     "2"     "1"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-24 11:56:35"
```

Comment: Why can't you use limit? Is this Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve all those fields or just MAX addDate?

Comment: All those fields, but only the latest one for a given id and userId. In the example for id 1 and userId 1, it'll be the second row from the table.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work, though there may be more efficient ways:

```
SELECT id, head, type, updated, userId, addedDate 
FROM test 
WHERE id = 1 
AND userId = 1
AND addedDate = (SELECT max(addedDate) FROM test WHERE id = 1 AND userId = 1)
```

I'm not sure how efficient a range query on a `DATE` type is in MySQL. There are schema changes you could make to give the same output, but I wouldn't worry about it until you see some form of bottleneck (and you won't until you reach millions of rows).

Worth noting - nothing about my solution guarantees that you will only get one row as output. If a user has two entries added at the exact same time, you will receive two rows in the output. In general, if you can't restrict the query to a `UNIQUE` column and you can't use `LIMIT 1`, you will have to rely on application logic ("we only insert once a day") to limit the results.

Comment: Why not immediately use the MAX value?

Comment: He wants the most recent record for a specific user. Without using a subquery you could only get the most recent record overall.

Comment: **SELECT max(addedDate) FROM test WHERE id = 1 AND userId = 1 will** return the most recent for a certain user and id

Comment: @nrathaus Look at the example output he wants to achieve. You can't do that with that form of query.

Comment: Now that you change the SQL it makes more sense, before it didn't

Comment: @ChrisHayes BTW is anything wrong with the way I've done it in my question, using limit. I asked this because someone said that doing it that way was inefficient. They would not say how. I feel what I've done is correct and ok...

Comment: @jmenezes I don't see any reason why you shouldn't use `LIMIT` in this case. In general you shouldn't worry too greatly about query optimization until and unless you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it

```
SELECT t.id, t.head, t.type, t.updated, t.userId, t.addedDate
  FROM
(
  SELECT userid, id, MAX(addeddate) addeddate
    FROM test
   WHERE userid = 1
     AND id = 1
) q JOIN test t
    ON q.userid = t.userid
   AND q.id = t.id
   AND q.addeddate = t.addeddate
```

or

```
SELECT id, head, type, updated, userId, addedDate
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, head, type, updated, userId, addedDate,
         @n := @n + 1 rnum
    FROM test t, (SELECT @n := 0) i
   WHERE userid = 1
     AND id = 1
   ORDER BY addedDate DESC
) q 
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

Output:

```
| ID | HEAD | TYPE | UPDATED | USERID |                       ADDEDDATE |
|----|------|------|---------|--------|---------------------------------|
|  1 |    2 |    1 |       1 |      1 | November, 24 2013 11:56:35+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c877f/11)** demo for both queries

Comment: Same caveat I added to my own answer - if `addeddate` is not unique, you may get multiple rows in the result.

Comment: @ChrisHayes addedDate will always be unique in this case. Do you see anything wrong with the sql I posted in `user3020494` comments?

Answer (score 1):

With mysql it's really simple:

```
select *
from (
  select * from test
  order by addedDate desc) x
group by userId
```

This gives you the latest row for every user. To get just one user:

```
select *
from (
  select * from test
  where userId = 1
  order by addedDate desc) x
group by userId
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how this replicates the effect of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @ChrisHayes you can google it yourself, but mysql has non-standard group by behaviour: where other databases explode if the group by clause doesn't list all non-aggregate columns, mysql returns the *first* row for each unique combination of columns listed in the group by clause

Comment: I see - thanks for explaining. I find it really hard to recommend relying on non-standard behavior, though.

Comment: @chris agreed: portability is desirable, but for a quick-n-dirty the ease of coding is hard to beat

Answer (score -1):

Select id, max(addedDate) from test where id=1 and userId=1

Comment: He wants to retrieve all the other columns as well.

Comment: @ChrisHayes No. Only the last added one for that id and userId

Comment: @jmenezes Your example output suggests that you want a single row with all columns.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Isn't that what his answer will do? I can add the other cols in there. Or do you see something wrong?

Comment: @jmenezes You can't add the other columns in there. Try it - you'll get an error because `MAX` is an aggregate function and the other columns are not aggregate values.

Comment: @Chris Hayes I did this and it worked fine! `Select id, max(addedDate),head, type from test where id=1 and userId=1;`

Comment: Apologies, you're right. You can run the query but it won't give you the right results. I was thinking of a `GROUP BY` clause. The query you're running will return every row in the table that matches the `WHERE` clause, but it will also have the timestamp of the most recent entry in the output.

Comment: @ChrisHayes It returns only the one with the latest timestamp for that id and userId.

Comment: @jmenezes MySQL appears to have a lot of crappy non-standard behavior. In PostgreSQL, the query causes an error as it is supposed to.

Comment: This is perfectly valid sql, its stupid that I got down-voted. Its ridiculous to blame mysql :)